# How to locate a path in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to locate a place on a machine(virtual path) in an ASP.NET APPLICATION,

the problem is this, In windows or desktop application we have .exe in debug folder so can refer other files relatively to .exe like ..\resources mean one folder upper of .exe there is a resouce folder, if i want to do the same in web application how to do that

Comment: How to locate what exactly? Be more specific

Comment: I guess you mean Server.MapPath?

Comment: You want to get files from \bin?

Comment: no folders relative to bin folder

Answer (score 2):

In the HttpContext you can find a lot of helpful properties

```
HttpRequest.ApplicationPath
HttpRequest.PhysicalApplicationPath
HttpRequest.PhysicalPath
```

and others.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116(v=vs.100).aspx 
There is a nice table with detailed explanations in the end of page.