# Using a relative path to a file in an .ashx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Double apologies - first, I'm completely new to ASP.net so I'm sure that this is a very naive question, and second, it looks like there's already a hundred questions on SO about relative paths in ASP.NET. Unfortunately - I can't find one that answers my question.

Background - I'm working on an `.ashx` file that needs to be able to access an Excel file.

When I'm running locally and using an absolute path to the file, everything works great. Here's my code:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="MyHandler" %>
using System;
... [a bunch more "usings..."]
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler {
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        string path = @"C:\Users\[...]\myExcelFile.xls";
        Workbook theWorkbook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        theWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Open(path);
```

However, I want to run this on a server, and use a relative path to the `myExcelFile.xls`.

My project is set up like this:

```
Main folder:
 - Default.aspx
 - myExcelFile.xls
 - Web.config
 - Global.asax
Styles folder
Scripts folder
Handler folder
 - MyHandler.ashx (that's reading the Excel File)
bin folder
```

So - you can see that the Excel file is in the "root" of the application.

To make the path relative, I've tried the following with no success:

Assuming that "relative" is from myHandler.ashx:

```
string path = @"..\myExcelFile.xls":
```

Assuming that `~` refers to the "root":

```
string path = @"~\myExcelFile.xls";
```

Just guessing:

```
string path = @".\myExcelFile.xls";
```

Just desperate:

```
string path = "myExcelFile.xls";
```

None of these worked.

So I did a little research here on SO, and found `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath`. So I tried:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("myExcelFile.xls");
```

That didn't work, but at least I could see that the value of `path` was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0\PinpointTool-DC.xls`

Of course - I don't understand that at all - that path is nowhere near where my project is (which means I don't understand what `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath` does...)

Last, I tried `Server.MapPath("myExcelFile.xls")`, but that doesn't work at all (locally, at least):

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context
```

So, how can I get this to work (ideally both locally and on a server?)

Comment: Did you try `Server.MapPath(@"~\myExcelFile.xls")` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813869/how-to-locate-a-path-in-asp-net-application/14813898#14813898 this might help

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: BTW, it's a horrible idea to use Office Interop in a service like asp.net.

Comment: @Joe - I will try `Server.MapPath(@"~\myExcelFile.xls")`, but **any** usage of `Server` causes an error when I run locally. I guess that makes sense, but ordinarily I like to get my app working locally before uploading & testing on my server. Does using `Server` make this impossible? Re: using Office Interop - I agree. But the requirements of this project are that I need to use an Excel spreadsheet as the "engine" of the calculations. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @John - you're definitely right - here's Microsoft on Office Interop on a server: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757. Sounds like much WORSE than a horrible idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could use [`context.Server.MapPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.server), You could also use a path that you define in your "web.config" file in the `appSettings` section and read it later in your application:

Web.config:

```
...
<appSettings>
    <add key="myBasePath" value="C:\Some\Path" />
</appSettings>
...
```

In your ASHX handler you could write something like:

```
...
string path = Path.Combine(
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"myBasePath"],
    @"myExcelFile.xls");
...
```

You can (and should) have different "web.config" files for your development machine and your production environment.

To second [John Saunders' remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026919/using-a-relative-path-to-a-file-in-an-ashx-page/15027125#comment21115757_15026919) regarding **Office Interop on the server**, I strongly recommend to use a decidated library like

- [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx) or
- [Spire.XLS](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/excel-for-net-introduce.html)

I worked successfully with both of them (commerical, though).

Comment: Uwe - thanks for you response. `context.Server.MapPath` works! I'm too much of a noob to know the difference between that and jbl's, so I hope I'm awarding the 'accepted answer' correctly. Re: Office Interop - I have conerns myself - seems inefficient for my server to open an instance of Excel each time a user calls the service. But this app will have virtually 0 chance of concurrent users (probably < 100/day), and the $$ of those products > my budget. Is office interop simply inefficient, or are there more serious issues?

Comment: @mattstuehler If you listen to [what the vendors of these libraries say](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Why+not+Automation), it is (of course ;-) more than just inefficiency.

Comment: If you had to pick either Aspose.Cells or Spire.XLS - which would you choose? In my project - I will start with a LARGE (+3mb) Excel workbook; my app needs to update a small number of cells with a user inputs, recalculate, then pull the values from a small number of 'result' cells. In other words - it's using an existing Excel workbook as a "calculation engine". (I don't need to create workbooks). It looks like both packages do at least that; which do you think does it better?

Comment: @mattstuehler I think Aspose.Cells is more mature.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/."),"myExcelFile.xls");
```

Hope this will help

Comment: @Anri yep, but forgot it after testing in a page... edited my answer

Comment: When you have an `HttpContext` instance on a silver plate (i.e. through the `context` variable), why bothering using the global static instance?

Comment: @UweKeim you're right. that's because I have been testing this in a page object.